# собрать Map<String, Object> из данных БД

Tags: java, mysql, json, строки, map

Есть таблица в БД (MySQL 5.7) которая имеет следующую структуру:

id | parent | key | value

при этом, `parent` - это ссылка на `id`

Таким образом мы получаем возможность "вкладывать" в элемент бесконечное множество других, запросом вида:

```
SELECT id,
       parent,
       key,
       value
FROM   (SELECT id,
               parent,
               key,
               value
        FROM   settings_tree
        ORDER  BY parent,
                  id) settings_tree,
       (SELECT @pv := :id) initialisation
WHERE  Find_in_set(parent, @pv)
       AND Length(@pv := Concat(@pv, ',', id))
```

получаю таблицу с перечисленными полями, где выбраны все записи имеющие отношение друг к другу по `parent` -> `id`

Вопрос в следующем, мне нужно пройтись по результатам выборки, чтобы собрать `Map<String, Object>` (где в качестве `value` может выступать опять же `Map`) и отдать его на стороне контроллера (по сути собрать json)

Если у вас есть на уме варианты порождения `String`, или другой структуры хранения данных, то тоже буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: *запросом вида* Ну этот запрос если и даст ожидаемый от него ответ - то только чисто случайно. И если он сегодня вдруг сподобился, то не факт, что завтра, или вообще при следующем выполнении, не вернёт какую-нибудь хрень голимую. Я уж не говорю о том, что достаточно одной записи, где parent_id > id, чтобы всё отправилось прямиком в мусор, и это настолько очевидно, что даже выполнять запрос не требуется.

Comment: *по сути собрать json* MySQL может и сам собрать и вернуть сразу нужный JSON. Особенно если версия актуальная.

Comment: по первому: запрос не вернет хрень, корректность записи гарантирована, речь не об этом, речь о том, как собрать json из этих данных.

по второму: к сожалению не может, версия 5.7 она умеет только форматировать json (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-functions.html) но самостоятельно строить из подобных структур нет

Comment: *корректность записи гарантирована* Исключено. Сортировка подзапроса однозначно игнорируется в основном запросе. Если записи всё же обрабатываются в порядке, определяемом этой сортировкой - это повезло. *как собрать json из этих данных* Пока не видно ни самих исходных данных, ни требуемого JSON. О чём вообще может идти речь? "как-то так"... устроит? а для более осмысленного ответа - недостаточно данных. *версия 5.7* Ура, нам сказали версию. Вот почему не с самого начала? И почему в комментарии, а не внесено в текст вопроса (да пожирнее) - информация, между прочим, критичная.

Comment: *она умеет только форматировать json .. но самостоятельно строить из подобных структур нет* Не надо говорить глупостей. Просмотри список агрегатных функций - вдруг и там найдётся парочка неучтённых, работающих с JSON?

Comment: повторю, корректность записи гарантирована. по поводу запроса - есть варианты лучше? с радостью выслушаю, но пока косяков не было, отсюда и уверенность в выдаче, можете ее пошатнуть, буду рад любой правке. что касается формата json - он всегда будет разный в зависимости от выбранного уровня (id), по этому его нельзя положить на заранее подготовленный объект, только карты. что касается агрегатных функций - известны варианты? помогите, это же форум, а не ферма где г... друг в друга кидают, я сюда за помощью пришел, а не чужое чсв потешить. ну а чтобы вы порадовались еще больше - MySQL 5.7.28

Comment: в общем, вопрос закрыт, я попробую разобрать рекурсией на уровне кода

Comment: *по поводу запроса - есть варианты лучше?* Повторюсь: "Пока не видно ни самих исходных данных, ни требуемого JSON". Пока не увижу, причём так, чтобы показанные значения не допускали неоднозначного толкования - никаких вариантов, само собой, не будет. Трудно предлагать что-то "вообще". *что касается формата json - он всегда будет разный в зависимости от выбранного уровня (id)* Какая разница-то? ну будет не один шаблон, а несколько разных, определяемых исходным уровнем. *что касается агрегатных функций - известны варианты?* ARRAYAGG(), OBJECTAGG().

Comment: данные в БД
https://a.radikal.ru/a28/2201/b3/ccf7e59265d8.png
примеры выборки
https://c.radikal.ru/c35/2201/c6/d20bb45abf1f.png
https://a.radikal.ru/a20/2201/63/83f4bd7aac61.png
https://c.radikal.ru/c01/2201/57/93c8ef592376.png

Comment: ничем не помогло, но спасибо, все сделал как и говорил, проблем нет